# How to type in ASCII ESC in vim/Linux using remote terminal tool

Tags: linux, vim, ascii

ENV = Centos7, bash version 4.2.46

---

**Main Goal** -
I want ANSI color codes to display colors instead of actual codes when using `cat` or `tail`.

---

**Current Status** -

If `sample.txt` contains codes as below

```
\e[32m green \e[0m
```

`cat sample.txt` will results in displaying the actual codes instead of its color.
[image]

---

**My Attempt** -

I tried
`echo -e "\e[32m green \e[0m" >> sample.txt`
which was transitioned into `^[[32m green ^[[0m` when I opened `sample.txt` with vi editor.
And it showed color when I `cat sample.txt`
[image]

---

**Question** -
How can I actually type in `^[` character inside vim or in console?
I found some people in stackoverflow saying I can type `CTRL + [` but it doesn't work.
I'm thinking it only works in pure Linux environment? But I can only use ssh remote tool from window.

*EDIT how do I type it in using VSCode?
When I download the script and open it, it shows red ESC box.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can type `CTRL+V` + `CTRL+[` in vi editor.